# Can a struct have several names?

Tags: c, struct

I am a beginner in C language, so I was seeking for some projects. And I found a project named bank management system. I went through the code and find this weird `struct`. Can anybody explain me this code snippet and how to use this kind of structs.

```C
struct {
    char name[60];
    int acc_no,age;
    char address[60];
    char citizenship[15];
    double phone;
    char acc_type[10];
    float amt;
    struct date dob;
    struct date deposit;
    struct date withdraw;
}add, upd, check, rem, transaction;  // What are those names? Are they several names for the `struct`?
```

And also this `struct` is in a function called menu. Can we use this `struct` in another function without passing it to function?

Comment: These are several variable declarations in the same "line": it declares the variables called "add", "upd", "check", and so on, each being of the same type as the struct before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sourav explained, `add` et al. are variables of type struct. This is usually discouraged if more definitions are required of this type.

If re-use of structs are intended, then a name needs to be mentioned while defining the struct, like the following:

```
struct foo {
  int a; etc.
} add, upd;
```

and then later,

```
struct foo check;
```

The scope of this definition is the same scope it is defined in. As you mentioned it is declared in a function, the scope of this is only that function.

Answer (score 2):

Here `add`, `upd`, `check`, `rem`, `transaction` are all variables of that structure type. The structure itself has no name, also known as unnamed struct.

To elaborate, the syntax for a structure declaration is:

```
      struct-or-union-specifier:
              struct-or-union identifier(opt) { struct-declaration-list }
```

where you can see the identifier is optional. So we can have unnamed structs.

Comment: and how can we use them?

Comment: @AeshaAmoli Just like any other structure variable.